# SPRK+ sphero not pairing to bluetooth (Ubuntu 14.04 and RasPi)

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, robotics, bluez

I'm trying to follow mmwise tutorial (https://github.com/mmwise/sphero_ros) to use my sphero SPRK+ in a ROS environment. I am unable to get the SPRK+ to connect to my PC using bluetoothctl or the bluetooth screen.

I have tried in both Oracle Virtualbox Ubuntu 14.04 with indigo ROS and Raspberry Pi 3 with ROS stretch. The error is exactly the same in both for the bluetoothctl, it is as follows:

```
[bluetooth]# pair F7:AF:AF:64:39:66
Attempting to pair with F7:AF:AF:64:39:66
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 Connected: yes
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 Connected: no
```

If I connect to the SPRK+ before pairing, it succeeds and changes to

```
[bluetooth]# connect F7:AF:AF:64:39:66
Attempting to connect to F7:AF:AF:64:39:66
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[NEW] Primary Service
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0008
        00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Generic Attribute Profile
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0008/char0009
        00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Service Changed
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0008/char0009/desc000b
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service000c
        22bb746f-2ba0-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service000c/char000d
        22bb746f-2ba1-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service000c/char000f
        22bb746f-2ba6-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service000c/char000f/desc0011
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012
        22bb746f-2bb0-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0013
        22bb746f-2bb1-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0013/desc0015
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0016
        22bb746f-2bb2-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0016/desc0018
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0019
        22bb746f-2bb6-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0019/desc001b
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0019/desc001c
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char001d
        22bb746f-2bb7-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char001d/desc001f
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0020
        22bb746f-2bb8-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0020/desc0022
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0023
        22bb746f-2bb9-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0023/desc0025
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0026
        22bb746f-2bba-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0026/desc0028
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0029
        22bb746f-2bbd-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char002b
        22bb746f-2bbe-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char002b/desc002d
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char002e
        22bb746f-2bbf-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char002e/desc0030
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0031
        22bb746f-3bba-7554-2d6f-726568705327
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0012/char0031/desc0033
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Primary Service
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0034
        00001016-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0034/char0035
        00001013-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0034/char0037
        00001017-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0034/char0039
        00001014-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5
        Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service0034/char0039/desc003b
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service003c
        0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Device Information
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service003c/char003d
        00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Hardware Revision String
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service003c/char003f
        00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Serial Number String
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service003c/char003f/desc0041
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service003c/char0042
        00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Model Number String
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service003c/char0044
        00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Manufacturer Name String
[NEW] Characteristic
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service003c/char0046
        00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Firmware Revision String
[NEW] Descriptor
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F7_AF_AF_64_39_66/service003c/char0046/desc0048
        00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Characteristic Format
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 UUIDs: 00001016-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 UUIDs: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 UUIDs: 22bb746f-2ba0-7554-2d6f-726568705327
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 UUIDs: 22bb746f-2bb0-7554-2d6f-726568705327
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 ServicesResolved: yes
[SK-3966]#
```

Then further attempt to pair results in

```
[SK-3966]# pair
Attempting to pair with
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device F7:AF:AF:64:39:66 Connected: no
```

Attempt to connect using the regular bluetooth settings screen in Ubuntu 14.04 results in Setting up "SK-3999" failed.

I've tried adding my pi user to the group lp as found in another post and I'm pretty sure my bluetooth on both is working fine, as it scans and finds things. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. That being said, this might be better asked on [su].

Answer (score 0):

Behavior of bluetoothctl you see is expected. In BLE, authentication and encryption are bound with Characteristics (data). When you try to connect with a peripheral device, GATT discovery happens, services get resolved and connection establishes successfully.

But, when you try to read or write data to/from the peripheral device for the first time, that's when the security requirements of the GATT service are verified and pairing request is generated and pairing takes place.

That is the reason `bluetoothctl connect` succeeds and `pair` is failing in your case.

If the GATT services on your peripheral device require authentication, then you 
may need to know the authentication pin depending on the IO capabilities of the device. Below is an example of authentication using bluetoothctl:

```
[bluetooth]# agent DisplayYesNo
Agent is already registered
[bluetooth]#pair 00:45:41:34:04:BA:8B
Request confirmation
[agent] Confirm passkey 547334 (yes/no): yes
```

Authentication methods in Bluetooth Low Energy depends on IO capabilities of the connecting devices. For example IO capabilities of a smart phone is KeyBoardDisplay, IO capabilities of a BLE wrist band is NoInputNoOutput. Documents of your BLE device in question should say more about its authentication method.